# Find all combination of numbers having sum N and includes exactly K elements using recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

**example:** f(k, n) should return [[1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [3, 1, 1]] 
 for k = 3 and n = 5.

All the subarrays have sum equal to 5 and there are exactly 3 elements in each subarray.

I've drawn recursion tree, but unable to implement a code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZHkV.jpg)

The idea behind building recursion tree is ->

- loop through 1 to k (`i` as iterator).
- Add `i` to list (say `arr`).
- Recursive call the function.
- Base condition is when length of list reaches k - 1 `(arr.length == k - 1)`
  then add n - (sum of all elements of `arr`) to the list and return the list.
- Add the list received by recursive call to `result` array.
- Return `result` array.

*Help me with an algorithm, just a pseudo code will work.*

Comment: Technically, `[1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1]` are the same because the order doesn't matter when you're doing `sum`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: To go from your recursion tree to an algorithm, you have to *generalize*; describe the way you built this recursion tree in a general way that would work not only for `k=3, n=5` but for any `k` and `n`. As a start, imagine I don't understand how you made this recursion tree, and I ask you to explain it to me. Can you explain how you did it?

Comment: And where is the problem with your program?

Comment: @NirAlfasi No, technically they are NOT the same.  They are different combinations of numbers that happen to be guaranteed to give the same result.

Comment: You know the answer to `f(1, n)`.  Next write code that takes the answer to `f(k-1, n-j)` and comes up with all the answers that start with `j`.  Then figure out how to write a loop and aggregate all of those answers together.

Comment: @btilly in that case it's not a combination. By the definition of _combination_, we don't care about the order of the elements in combinations.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I want the output as it is, what would be appropriate replacement for the word combination, and would you please help me with the algorithm I've clarify the approach I was following.

Comment: @NirAlfasi The word "combination" as used in English (and informally by other mathematicians) does not match how it is used in combinatorics.  The meaning of the question is easy to figure out.  Is there a point to your nitpicking?

Comment: The word that should be used is "permutations", not "combinations". I don't think it's nitpicking asking to use the correct terminology and I never heard of a mathematician that used combinations & permutations interchangeably but what do I know, I have only a M.Sc. in Mathematics... As for this question, giving you the answer will not help you learn. The advice that btilly gave you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323961/find-all-combination-of-numbers-having-sum-n-and-includes-exactly-k-elements-usi?noredirect=1#comment115493830_65323961) is good - follow it.

Comment: @NirAlfasi `[2, 2, 1]` and `[1, 1, 3]` are two of the things that were meant, and are not permutations of each other.  Either formally or informally.   So permutations is not the word that should be used for this problem.  If you want to be formal you could say "ordered sets of numbers".  Incidentally I also have advanced math degrees, and I've certainly heard people say "combinations" very loosely in other contexts.

Comment: As an example, ever heard of a "combination lock"?  There are more people who are familiar with the order mattering on the combination needing to unlock one of those than are familiar with the use of the word "combination" in combinatorics!

Comment: @btilly "ordered sets of numbers" sounds good to me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

This problem requires recursion.  And as the old saying goes, to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

The trick is to first write a function that will work for the boundary cases:

```
def f(n, k):
    if n < k or k < 1:
        return [] # No solutions
    elif k == 1:
        return [n] # One solution
    else:
        ...
```

Now in the ... bit we can assume that `f` works for `k-1`.  We just want it to work for `k`.  Here is pseudocode that is deliberately not executable to show how to do that.

```
def f(n, k):
    if n < k or k < 1:
        return [] # No solutions
    elif k == 1:
        return [[n]] # One solution
    else:
        answer = []
        for j in 1..(n-k):
            for partial_solution in f(n-j, k-1):
                add j to partial_solution
                add partial_solution to answer
        return answer
```

The mental exercise is, "Imagine that I had a working function, how would I use that to construct a working function?"  It feels like pulling yourself up by your bootstraps.  But it actually works as long as your recursive function always calls itself with simpler and simpler arguments, eventually getting down to the base case that you already implemented.